# Asterisk simultaneous AMI calls

Tags: asterisk

I would like to make e.g. 10 simultaneous calls via AMI. My *sip.conf* looks like this:

;
[multi_auto_dial_origin]
exten => _09XX0,1,NoOp()
        same => n,Answer()
        same => n,Wait(30)
;
[multi_auto_dial_destination]
exten => _00XXXXX,1,NoOp()
        same => n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN:2})
;

and my *telnet* data is e.g. as follows:

ACTION: Originate
Channel: Local/09000@multi_auto_dial_origin
Callerid: 3125551212 
Exten: 0016371
Priority: 1
Context: internal
Async: true

So, when the AMI receives it it will first dial on **Local/09000** and if it answers the number **0016371** will be ringing.

**This works fine but...**

...when I want to make a second call I have to **wait 1s** and then start the AMI session.
If I start it earlier e.g. after 500ms from the first call or immediately the Asterisk will not dial to the second number.

I noticed in the Asterisk's log that the value **${EXTEN:2}** is empty. But I saw in the Wireshark that my application sends proper value, so there is no problem at this layer.
I believe that it is something in SIP Server which has a problem with accepting immediate calls or maybe I did something wrong.

Do you have any idea how to 'fix' it?

Comment: Hi, Could you add the wireshark trace? Which exact Asterisk version are you running?

Comment: Currently I do not have the Wireshark traces, maybe I will put them later. But I saw that the Telnet sends full proper data and Asterisk responds with the *Success* message. I assume that the problem is after it receive the message and performs dialing.
My Asterisk is 1.8.21.0

Comment: Are you opening and closing the AMI session, or leaving it open and issuing each Originate in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Close the AMI session after originating the call.
[Here the example to close session](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Logoff)

Action: Logoff
Parameters: None